# How to catch event handlers created by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on project where a lot of legacy code in jQuery creates onChange, onClick handlers in many different places. 
When running the app - I see all kind of strange functionality, than it takes me a while to reverse eng. & find the place of the action.

Is there an easy way to set some breakpoint and catch all or some specific `jquery.on('...` functions?

Upd: main issue is, handlers added and removed all the time. Sometime selectors are not so trivial (for example 3rd child of `tr` under specific class).
I do know how to use dev-tools, I looking for smart way to shorten way of reverse engineering and get to the right place in call stack where the handler created/added.

Comment: You can select the Element in dev tools and see all eventlisteners there.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overwrite the `on` function with a function that intercepts the registration of an event handler, with a function that contains a `debugger` statement as well as a call to the event handler. Like this:

```js
const oldOn = jQuery.fn.on;
jQuery.fn.extend({
  on(...args) {
    const f = args.pop();
    oldOn.call(this, ...args, function(...args) {
      debugger;
      f.call(this, ...args);
    });
  }
});

jQuery( "#box" ).on( "click", function() {
  console.log( 'clicked' );
});
```

```css
#box {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Note: `debugger` doesn't work on SO, but it does on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7kr5y2d8/2/